# RavenDb increased startup time of winform app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ravendb

I use ravendb as embedded database in my winforms project. Everything works as it should but I do need to check with someone startup time of winform main window. When I'm added IDocumentStore initialization startup time is increased by 5,6 seconds.

inside MainForm.cs I have

```
private IDocumentStore store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { 
            RunInMemory = false };

public MainForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   store.Initialize();
}
```

am I doing something wrong here with IDocumentStore instance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this an Embedded instance and it takes RavenDB a few seconds to initialize the store, that is expected.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to access the database right away, you might consider launching the application first, and then initializing it in a separate thread.  You'd have to have some kind of "loading..." indicator in your UI, and a flag to check if the initialization is complete so you don't attempt to access the database before it is fully initialized.

Comment: considering your advice I created question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19587670/initializing-repository-in-separated-thread-issue