# initializing repository in separated thread issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Inside MainForm.cs I'm initializing  couple of things (IBookRepository and IDocumentStore).

```
private IDocumentStore _store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {RunInMemory = false };
private IBookRepository _repository;
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _store.Initialize();
    _repository = new RavenDbBookRepository(_store);
}
```

since embeddable document store takes a while (5,6 sec) to init I want to move it's initialization on separate thread

so I tried

```
 private void InitOnNewThread()
    {
        _store.Initialize();
        _repository = new RavenDbBookRepository(_Store);            
    }

public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InitOnNewThread));
    t.Start();
}
```

but using this _repository is null inside main thread, cause is populated in separate thread.

Since this is first time I trying to work with thread I don't see how to overcome this.\

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the new `async` and `await` keywords.

```
public class MainForm : Form
{
  private IDocumentStore _store = new EmbeddableDocumentStore {RunInMemory = false };
  private IBookRepository _repository;

  private async void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs args)
  {
    // Do stuff here that does not depend on _store or _repository.
    await InitializeRepositoryAsync();
    // Now you can use _store and _repository here.
  }

  private Task InitializeRepositoryAsync()
  {
    return Task.Run(
      () =>
      {
        _store.Initialize();
        _repository = new RavenDbBookRepository(_store);
      };
  }
}
```

The neat thing about how `await` works is that it will preempt the execution of `MainForm_Load` while the task is running asynchronously in the background. After the task completes the remaining portion of `MainForm_Load` will be injected back into the execution stream of the UI thread. It is really quite clever how this works and makes for a really elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read a bit about the Singleton Pattern, and about using it in multi-threaded environments.

Since you mention RavenDB's DocumentStore, you may find this handy: http://ayende.com/blog/160161/managing-ravendb-document-store-startup. Initializing the document store lazily is a good option vs doing this on app load.

Answer (score -1):

You can use .Join()

```
public MainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(InitOnNewThread));
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
```

This will wait until the repo is ready before continuing

Comment: This will block the main UI thread and obviously not what the OP wants